# Socket.io automatically serves its client-side javascript, when you wire it to the server

Tags: node.js, express

Here's a minimal example of node.js/express.js/socket.io server. It shouldn't be serving anything but `index.html` from `/` path.

`server.js:`

```javascript
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var socketio = require('socket.io');

// create server
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = socketio(server);

// set routes for express
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    console.log('index.html is NOT served by static middleware');
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + '/../client/index.html'));
});

// start listening
server.listen(9000, function(){
   console.log('listening on 9000');
});
```

I run it with `node server.js` command. It serves `index.html` as `localhost:9000/` successfully.

But for some strange reason it also serves `/socket.io/socket.io.js` from `node_modules` directory, which it shouldn't. Why? Here's my index.html file:

`index.html`

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Websocket + RabbitMQ + Express</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script src="client.js"></script>
  <div id="messages"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's about simplicity, there's no need for socket.io and http if you're using express. Try this code below for your server.js:

```js
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log('index.html is NOT served by static middleware');
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + '/../client/index.html'));
});

app.listen(9000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 9000!');
})
```

This way, only client will resolve socket.io and server will only be responsible for serving a static page

Comment: In fact, I just localized the source of this: addition of socket.io line makes server serve from `node_modules`: `var io = socketio(server);` When I remove it, browser curses about `can't load /socket.io/socket.io.js`. It appears that socket.io serves itself unannounced.